# Customize the default message for a rule

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Is there a way to customize the default message for an invalid rule in jQuery Validate plugin?

I mean something like

> whenever a field is required, and I
>   have not specified a custom message,
>   the message should be "custom message"

I have tried this code but without success

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    messages: { 
        required: "custom message"
    }
});
```

Comment: There is more than one validation plugin for jQuery; which one are you talking about exactly?

Comment: Sorry. I am talking about `http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
  required: "custom message",
});
```